# ORACLE SQL - How to find number of purchases made before, during, and after birthday month?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to find the number of purchases made a month before & after a customer's birthday month.

For eg. Customer A's birthday is in June. I would like to know how many purchases he made in May, June and July.

I have 2 existing tables which look like the following:

PURCHASE HISTORY TABLE:

```
CUSTOMER_ID        PURCHASE_DATE
1                  2019-06-18
1                  2019-05-23
1                  2019-04-19
1                  2019-04-01
2                  2019-03-10
2                  2019-02-28
2                  2018-02-11
2                  2018-02-02

Note: This table only contains transaction history. Dates without purchases are not recorded.
```

CUSTOMER DETAILS TABLE:

```
CUSTOMER_ID        DATE_OF_BIRTH
1                  1996-05-22
2                  1990-03-07
```

How the output should look like:

```
CUSTOMER_ID          BDAY_MONTH       PURCHASE_B4_BDAY        PURCHASE_BDAY       PURCHASE_AFTER_BDAY
1                    5                2                       1                   1
2                    3                1                       1                   0

where PURCHASE_B4_BDAY = number of purchases made 1 month before birthday month
and   PURCHASE_BDAY = number of purchases made during birthday month
and   PURCHASE_AFTER_BDAY = number of purchases made 1 month after birthday month
```

Note: I only want to take into account the latest year of purchase.
For eg, customer id 2 has 1 purchases in Feb'19 and 2 purchases in Feb'18, however, only the ones made in Feb'19 should be considered.

Do let me know if you require more information, thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the difference of the months between purchase and birth date and use `MOD` function to calculate if the purchase is made one month before, or on the exact month or one month after birth month as follows:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_OF_BIRTH),
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHS_ = 11 THEN 1 END) AS PURCHASE_B4_BDAY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHS_ = 0 THEN 1 END) AS PURCHASE_BDAY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHS_ = 1 THEN 1 END) AS PURCHASE_AFTER_BDAY
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CD.CUSTOMER_ID,
            MOD(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(PH.PURCHASE_DATE, 'MONTH'), 
                               TRUNC(CD.DATE_OF_BIRTH, 'MONTH')), 12) AS MONTHS_,
            PH.PURCHASE_DATE,
            CD.DATE_OF_BIRTH
        FROM
            PURCHASE_HISTORY PH
            JOIN CUSTOMER_DETAILS CD ON PH.CUSTOMER_ID = CD.CUSTOMER_ID
    )
WHERE MONTHS_ IN(1, 0, 11) 
GROUP BY CD.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Let me know if you find any difficulty in a given solution.

Cheers!!